# wordpress plugin including javascript

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin. i have included my JavaScript like this:

```
wp_register_script('woo_tool_js', plugins_url('tooltip.js', __FILE__) );
wp_enqueue_script('woo_tool_js');
```

I would like to be able to add php to the .js file. What would be the best way to go about this. this is what i have in my tooltip.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".infobfn").append('<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="<?php echo $var1; ?>"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a>');
});
</script>
```

I have read into jquery .load, but i am quite new to jquery and dont fully understand how it works.

If someone could post an example up of how to enqueue a script which can contain php, that would be great.

Comment: If it where me, I would at least start by changing that DOM ready handler to [something that works](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) instead of attempting to dynamically generate your script.

This will allow you to access any variables you build in your script within the rendered javascript. For example:

```
wp_register_script('woo_tool_js', plugins_url('tooltip.js', __FILE__) );
wp_localize_script('woo_tool_js', 'my_data', array(
    'key' => 'value'
));

wp_enqueue_script('woo_tool_js');
```

...will allow you to access the `my_data` array as an object in your javascript:

```
console.log(my_data);
```